# Replacing entire string if there is a matching word

Tags: python, regex

I've got a large list of words that I'm trying to cleanup. A number of those words appear multiple times written a little differently every time and I would like to normalize them. For instance I would like to replace the following words:

```
list = ["resident super", "super live in", "on site superintendent in building", "livein super", "residential super", "superintendent lives in", "on-site super"...]
```

with just `superintendent`

I figured I could do this with

```
for item in list:
    re.sub("resident super|super live in|on site superintendent in building| livein super|residential super|superintendent lives in|on-site super", 
           "superintendent", list)
```

but I'm certain to miss some entries. All the entries include the word `super`, but is there a way to have a regex rule that will replace the entire item with the desired word?

Comment: the problem is that you want to replace a list of space-separated words by a word. So you have to be exhaustive, or the regex won't know when to start/stop replacing words. For instance: `I am the super live in man`: where do I start/stop replacing?

Comment: if your "words" are provided line by line, then a simple match against `\bsuper\b` and you can replace the entire string.

Comment: I was thinking of using the `for` loop to iterate through each member of the list. If that member would contain the word `super` then the entire member should be replaced by `superintendent`.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre, I've attempted `\bsuper\b` but my list remains completely unchanged.

Comment: sort the different branches of your alternation by string length in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `re.sub` method doesn't replace a string in place. It can't, since strings in Python are immutable. When you do a substitution on a string, it returns a new string with the requested changes (or the original string if there was no match). You're currently ignoring the return value, so your code has no effect.

But I don't think you actually need regular expressions at all for this issue. If you want to replace any string that mentions the word `super` anywhere with the string `"superintendent"`, you can use a simple substring test:

```
for i, item in enumerate(list_of_strings):
    if "super" in item:
        list_of_strings[i] = "superintendent"
```

This will of course be more prone to false-positives than using your current regex. You could still use the structure of the code above with a regex search if you want (just change the `if "super" in item:` line to `if re.search(pattern, item):` after setting `pattern` to a regex that matches the strings you want it to).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but if you want to replace every element with the word `super` in it by `superintendant`, here's what I would do.

```
for index,element in enumerate(listToCheck):
    if "super" in element:
        listToCheck[index]="superintendant"
```

By the way don't name your variables `list` because it's a reserved python keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but couldn't you use `in` instead? This doesn't seem to warrant regex as regex is significantly slower.

For instance:

```
i=0
while i < len(list):
    if 'super' in list[i]:
        list[i] = 'superintendant'
    i+=1
```

This will replace everything in your list that contains `super` with `superintendent`

Answer (score 1):

Shortest with a list comprehension:

```
lst = ["resident super", "super live in", "on site superintendent in building", 
"livein super", "residential super", "superintendent lives in", "on-site super", "mega-intendent"]

new_lst = ['superintendent' if 'super' in item else item 
            for item in lst]

print(new_lst)
# ['superintendent', 'superintendent', 'superintendent', 'superintendent', 'superintendent', 'superintendent', 
# 'superintendent', 'mega-intendent']
```